# Jupyter Multi-line Cursor with Mac

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ide, jupyter, multicursorediting

Does anyone know if this is possible to do on a mac?

http://swanintelligence.com/multi-cursor-in-jupyter.html

It looks like they are highlighting the entire text block and then getting multi-line cursors. I try doing this with `option + mouse selection` and then `cmd + mouse click` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is pretty cool. here's how I did it
`option(alt) + mouse selection`

then, instead of `cmd + click` try `cmd + "right key"`

this should multi-select all the ending rows

*`option(alt) + "right key"` instead of `cmd + click` seems to work as well, along with `cmd + "right key"`